# c++ to Java translation

Tags: java, c++, translation

Can someone be so kind and check my C++ to Java translation?

This is the first part of the c++ code I need to translate (part of the rtcmix library http://rtcmix.org/) :

```
static void trans(float a, float alpha, float b, int n, double *output){
       int i;
       float delta, interval = 0.0;
       delta = b - a;
       if (n <= 1) {
           *output = a;
           return;
       }
       interval = 1.0 / (n - 1.0);
       if (alpha != 0.0) {
          float denom = 1.0 / (1.0 - exp((double) alpha));
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          *output++ = a + delta * (1.0 - exp((double) i * alpha * interval)) * denom;
       }
       else
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
           *output++ = a + delta * i * interval;
}
```

and this is my java translation:

```
    static void trans(float a, float alpha, float b, int n, double output){
           int   i;
           float delta, interval = 0;
           delta = b - a;
           if (n <= 1) {
              output = a;
              return;
           }
           interval = (float) (1.0 / (n - 1.0));
           if (alpha != 0.0) {
              float denom = (float) (1.0 / (1.0 - Math.exp((double) alpha)));
                  else
                  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                  output++;
                  output= a +delta * i * interval;
               }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be nice to run your code with yourself and than if you find any issue come up with the problem?

Comment: In the C variant, `output` is an array, so the statement `*output++ = ...` means that the current position in the array is assigned the expression, then advance to the next place in the array.

Comment: @umesh no, because this is only the first part and Im stuck at the second one

Comment: in java code return value of `output` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Since you have made a reasonable attempt, here is how I would write it.

```
static void trans(double a, double alpha, double b, double[] output) {
    double delta = b - a;
    if (output.length <= 1) {
        output[0] = a;
        return;
    }
    double interval = 1.0 / (output.length - 1);
    if (alpha != 0) {
        double denom = 1 / (1 - Math.exp(alpha));
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = a + (1 - Math.exp(i * alpha * interval)) * delta * denom;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = a + i * delta * interval;
    }
}
```

---

In your case `n` and `output` would be one parameters in Java

```
static void trans(float a, float alpha, float b, double[] output)
```

'n' is the length of the array which is `output.length` in java.

BTW: its a bit pointless using float of calculations with only 7 digits of accuracy and using double to store the values with 16 digits of accuracy.  You might concider doing it the other way around.

---

If you have a method which returns a double, it should use `return` instead of passing via a parameter (even in C++)

Instead of assigning to output, remove it and use `return value` instead.

Comment: you mean instead of output++ return output?

Comment: neither. You have a method which returns multiple values using a provided array.

Comment: ok.. now I'm starting to understand this method. Thanks a lot for the revision and the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
                static double trans(float a, float alpha, float b, int n, double output){
       int   i;
       float delta, interval = 0;
       delta = b - a;
       if (n <= 1) {
          output = a;
          return;
       }
       interval = (float) (1.0 / (n - 1.0));
       if (alpha != 0.0) {
          float denom = (float) (1.0 / (1.0 - Math.exp((double) alpha)));
              else
              for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
              output++;
              output= a +delta * i * interval;
           } return output; }
```

this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work, as Java doesn't have reference variables. You will need to return `output` at the end of the function and change the calling code to use the return value. Start by changing the method signature to `static double[] trans(...`.

You should also set the method access level to public or private depending on where the method is to be called from.

I see several curly brackets are also missing, so your indentation is actually misleading - fixing that would be a good first step ;)

Also note that `output` actually seems to be an array of size `n` in the original code, not a simple double.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original source again:

```
static void trans(float a, float alpha, float b, int n, double *output)
{
   int i;
   float delta, interval = 0.0;
   delta = b - a;
   if (n <= 1) {
       *output = a;
       return;
   }
   interval = 1.0 / (n - 1.0);
   if (alpha != 0.0) {
      float denom = 1.0 / (1.0 - exp((double) alpha));
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      *output++ = a + delta * (1.0 - exp((double) i * alpha * interval)) * denom;
   }
   else
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       *output++ = a + delta * i * interval;
}
```

The pointer parameter double *output is used to access an array. In Java you have to declare it as an array.

```
static void trans(float a, float alpha, float b, int n, double [] output)
{
    // Check that the array is big enough.
    // If it is too small: do nothing.
    if (output.length < n)
    {
        return;
    }

    int i;
    float delta, interval = 0;
    delta = b - a;
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        output[0] = a;

        return;
    }

    interval = (float) (1.0 / (n - 1.0));
    if (alpha != 0.0)
    {
        float denom = (float) (1.0 / (1.0 - Math.exp((double) alpha)));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            output[i] = a + delta * (1.0 - Math.exp((double) i * alpha * interval)) * denom;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            output[i] = a + delta * i * interval;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I just overlooked that the exp() function was already used in the code. Corrected Java code.

Comment: Looks amazing Giorgio. Thanks so much for that. I guess with find the function you mean import Java Math and then:  output[i] = a + delta * (1.0 - Math.exp((double) i * alpha * interval)) * denom;